# JSP form values passed to a servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a form in JSP in the following manner :

```
<form id="provision-field" method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myServlet">

    <fieldset>
        <ol class="fields">

            <li>
                <label for="field1">field1</label>
                <input type="text" id="field1" "
                        value="<%= field1 %>"

                        />
                <span class="description">
                    <span class="optional">Optional</span>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions">
        <button type="submit" name="Submit">
            Submit form
        </button>
        <a href="" class="close-dialog">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a js snippet on click of the submit button does the following

```
var field = document.getElementById("field1").value;   

 $.ajax({
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myServlet'
                type: 'POST',
                data: field,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(html) {

                  alert("Success");
                },
                error: function(error){
                alert("ERROR");
                }
                });
```

When I just use the form element (ie take out the js code) , I can reach my servlet but none of my form parameters are passed . when I try using the js code , the ajax request does not work . could someone point to me how this should be correctly done .

The servlet code is :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       logger.info("Inside the post function");
        logger.info(request.getParameter("data");

    }
```

Comment: Please share servlet code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var field = document.getElementById("field1").value;   

    $.ajax({
        url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myServlet'
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            data :field
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {

          alert("Success");
        },
        error: function(error){
        alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
```

Inside servelt following code in doPost method :
Assuming that you have primary knowledge of HttpServlet...

```
    request.getParameter("data");
```

I am sharing small Ajax with Servlet tutorial , which may help you for further problem... [Download Link- AJAX Servlet Tutorial](http://mediafire.com/?93xa1dm48q5h1ym)

Comment: Can you share your Servlet code ?
..
Try for alert(field);......... before doing ajax and check that value shown in alert box or not... Please also remove <form>...</from>, If you doing AJAX than u should not use form tag...

Comment: Hey added the servlet code , when I alert the value it works , but when  I do the request.getParameter call , it just displays a blank

Comment: I am sharing you small Ajax with Servlet tutorial , which may help you for further problem... http://www.mediafire.com/?93xa1dm48q5h1ym

Answer (score 0):

`data: { field1:field1Value }`  send like this

and then access `request.getParameter("field1");` in servlet

Answer (score 0):

As form submission method is post  `method="post"`, you need to make sure you are fetching request values in `doPost(request, response)` method